# Email Validation for Azure AD B2C Signin Userflow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created a userflow for Signin using Azure AD B2C. I have enabled MFA (Multifactor authentication) so that when I click on Signin button the flow goes through some authentication. In Azure its phone authentication by default. Can i make it email authentication with just Azure side configuration?

[This is the MFA i am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hcEJ.png)

[This is my signin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXRlr.png)

[This is the phone validation page i get when i click on signin button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuhpI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In step 7 set the type of MFA to email
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-user-flow#set-multi-factor-authentication

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. Yes i noticed while creation of user flow we can select MFA which can be either email, phone etc.